# Background image stretch and opacity not working

Tags: qt, styles

I'm trying to style my app a little bit. So I added a background image and I want it to be stretchy with no repeat and with a little opacity. I'm using this code:

```
this->centralWidget()->setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/image.jpg) 
                                     0 0 0 0 
                                     stretch stretch; 
                                     opacity: 50; 
                                     background-repeat: no-repeat;
                                     background-position: center;");
```

But the opacity and stretching seems not to work.

Comment: Have you tried using just `background` instead of `background-image`?

Comment: @SilvanoCerza still the same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Opacity is supported only for QTooltip in QSS.
To stretch the background you can try with **border-image** instead of background-image, like this:

```
this->centralWidget()->setStyleSheet("border-image: url(:/image.jpg) 
0 0 0 0 stretch stretch;");
```

But be careful with the aspect ratio.
For the opacity you could try to apply a [QGraphicsOpacityEffect](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsopacityeffect.html) with this (untested) snippet of code:

```
QGraphicsOpacityEffect* op = new QGraphicsOpacityEffect(this);
op.setEnabled(true);
op.setOpacity(0.5); // 0 is transparent, 1 means opaque
this->centralWidget()->setGraphicsEffect(op);
```